# Do animals that sleep during the day have a different sleep architecture than those who sleep at night?

Tags: sleep, physiology

A typical hypnogram, delineating the sleep architecture for a (human) mammal looks like

[image]

A distinct distribution of non-REM and REM sleep can be observed.

Is this pattern of sleep cycles particular to that of diurnal mammals, and if so, how would the sleep architecture of a mammal that sleeps during the daytime be different?

Comment: I looked for research on this, interestingly I couldn't find any scientific articles looking at sleep-wake cycles in nocturnal creatures. Fascinating question, but based on the lack of research available I doubt the answer is available at present. Although I hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One study (Zhao et. al., 2010), investigating the sleep architecture of two bat species (one nocturnal, and one mixed), notes the following:

> *C. sphinx* was found to sleep predominantly throughout the day (60% of total sleep quota) during which time it spent significantly longer
>   time in NREM and REM sleep. Compared to *E. spelaea*, *C. sphinx* had
>   significantly less REM and NREM sleep episodes but their duration was
>   significantly longer. *E. spelaea* appears to distribute its time at
>   wake and in REM and NREM sleep equally throughout the light and dark
>   phases.

[image: Bat sleep architecture]
Top three rows are for the predominantly nocturnal bat *C. sphinx*. Note the "Wake" rows for the two species.

Source:

[Zhao, X., Sun, H., Tang, Z., Flanders, J., Zhang, S., & Ma, Y. (2010). *Characterization of the sleep architecture in two species of fruit bat.* Behavioural brain research, 208(2), 497-501.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jon_Flanders/publication/40821192_Characterization_of_the_sleep_architecture_in_two_species_of_fruit_bat/links/00b4952974f1cb971e000000.pdf)